# SharePoint 2013 - How to make title page editable within Publishing page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

If I place the following tag within my custom page layout:

```
<!--MS:<SharePoint:FieldValue FieldName="Title" runat="server"/>-->
```

I can clearly see that it displays the title of the page.

But how can I convert this into an input box when I go to **edit** my publishing page, and simply change the value from this input box?  What would the code look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [TextField control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.textfield.aspx), instead of a FieldValue.
A FieldValue is always read-only, even in an EditModePanel (see my comment as well).

So, just replace "FieldValue" with "TextField" and you should be good to go. It will render a label in display mode, and a text box in edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

you should insert a snippet in you page layout that containing a panel `EditModePanel` and inside of the `EditModePanel` you should insert the reference of field want show in edition mode

a Example without snippet:

```
<PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel runat=server id="EditModePanelA" PageDisplayMode="Display">
       <SharePointWebControls:FieldValue runat="server" id="ImageFieldValue" FieldName="PublishingPageImage"/>
       <SharePointWebControls:FieldValue runat="server" id="ImageFieldValue2" FieldName="PageImage2"/>
</PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
```

with snippet would be something as this: (I think it would be of this so, sorry)

```
<!--MS:<PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel runat=server id="EditModePanelA" PageDisplayMode="Display">
       <SharePointWebControls:FieldValue runat="server" id="ImageFieldValue" FieldName="PublishingPageImage"/>
       <SharePointWebControls:FieldValue runat="server" id="ImageFieldValue2" FieldName="PageImage2"/>
</PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>-->
```

Comment: SOrry this is not true. It would only display them, in edit mode. An EditModePanel is meant to only show those controls in EditMode.